# Polynomials through successive differences

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $h_0:\Bbb{N}\rightarrow\Bbb{N}$ be any function. Define recursively, for $m>0$,
$$h_{r+1}(m)=h_r(m)-h_r(m-1).$$

Suppose that for some $k>0$ we have $h_k(m)\equiv d$ constant.

Is this sufficient to show that $h_0$ has to be a polynomial (of degree $k$) in $m$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is enough to show that $h_0$ is a polynomial of degree at most $k$. If you stipulate that $d\ne0$, then its degree will be exactly $k$.

You can verify that if $p(x) = ax^k + $ lower order terms is a polynomial of positive degree, then $p(x)-p(x-1) = akx^{k-1} +$ lower order terms. That shows you that polynomials have the appropriate property. Furthermore, this discrete derivative is reversible up to an additive constant. Indeed, $h_{r+1}(m) = h_r(m) - h_r(m-1)$ means that
$$
h_r(m) = h_r(0) + \sum_{j=1}^m h_{r+1}(j),
$$
so that $h_r$ can be recovered from $h_{r+1}$ and $h_r(0)$. That's enough to show that $k_0$ must be a polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to Newton interpolation. Divided differences, here the divisor is always 1, give the interpolation coefficients.

A recent related (but not equivalent) question was to show that if the interpolation polynomial of d+1 sample points always has degree d-1, then the original function is actually a polynomial of degree d-1.